# Coerce from custom datatype to Maybe

Tags: haskell

I have:

```hs
data Time a = NoTime | Time a
```

and I want to convert it by rules:

```
NoTime -> Nothing
Time a -> Just a
```

`Time a` and `Maybe a` are isomorphic types (yes?), but it seems I cannot coerce `Time a` to `Maybe a` (due to "custom type error"). What is the most elegant and maybe shortest way to do it (not plain `case`)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `case` is the most elegant and shortest way to do this. Unless you just want to scrap your data type and say `type Time a  = Maybe a`.

Comment: With `Generic Time` you can roundtrip through the generic representation, if you wanted to `coerce` the only way is to define `newtype Time a = Time_ (Maybe a) deriving newtype (Functor, Applicative, Monad)`. Then you can define pattern synonyms `{-# Complete NoTime, Time #-}` with `pattern NoTime = Time_ Nothing` and `pattern Time a = Time_ (Just a)` and you don't even need to export the `Time_` constructor. Like amalloy says you can use `unsafeCoerce` which should work but there is no guarantees that the datatype is represented the same way; also you can't derive instances via `Maybe`.

Comment: There is also [Deriving Isomorphically](https://www.tweag.io/blog/2020-04-23-deriving-isomorphically/) but for that you need to specify the isomorphism anyway. I guess technically you could find a way to derive that via roundtripping.

Comment: `newtype` is currently the only way to introduce representational equality in GHC but the paper, [Safe Zero-cost Coercions for Haskell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2018/05/coercible-JFP.pdf) "8.5 What else is there to coerce?" discusses the option of an induced ``Maybe a `Coercible` Time a`` axiom without a newtype but I haven't seen further discussion of including that as a feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Data.Coerce.coerce` requires more than isomorphism. It is only capable of navigating newtype wrappers. You have two unrelated types which happen to have the same representation, and `coerce` can't do anything with that.

`unsafeCoerce` would probably work, but it's obviously unsafe, and I don't think there is any guarantee that types with a similar structure must be represented the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite an answer, but an extended comment, if you unwisely decide to use `unsafeCoerce`.

It is "safe enough" to `unsafeCoerce` a `Time a` value to and from a `Maybe a` value.  This relies on GHC laying out `Time a` and `Maybe a` in exactly the same way in memory, and even though there's no technical guarantee of this, current versions of GHC do so, and it's pretty much inconceivable that this behavior would change in future versions.

There are a few things you need to be aware of, though.  First, you need to make sure that `Time`'s definition is identical in structure to `Maybe`'s.  In `base`, we have:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

and so we must have the exact definition:

```
data Time a = NoTime | Time a
```

It will not work if the constructors are in opposite order.  The result will be either an incorrect result or a runtime crash:

```
data BadTime a = Time a | NoTime   -- WILL NOT WORK!
```

Also, it's very dangerous to use `unsafeCoerce` directly.  The following will appear to work:

```
main = print (unsafeCoerce (Just 1) :: Time Int)
```

by printing `Time 1`, but the types are wrong.  The type of `Just 1` defaults to `Maybe Integer`, and it can't actually be safely `unsafeCoerce`d to a `Time Int`.  It just happens to work for "small" integers and will fail completely if you try to coerce to a different numeric type.  This:

```
main = print (unsafeCoerce (Just 1) :: Time Double)
```

prints `Time 5.0e-324`, for example.

So, you'll need to write "safe" wrappers with type signatures that enforce equality of the type parameter `a` to have any hope of safely using this unsafe coercion:

```
toTime :: Maybe a -> Time a
toTime = unsafeCoerce

fromTime :: Time a -> Maybe a
fromTime = unsafeCoerce
```

and if you have to write the wrapper anyway, you might as well use safe versions, since you'll only have to write them once:

```
toTime :: Maybe a -> Time a
toTime Nothing = NoTime
toTime (Just x) = Time x

fromTime :: Time a -> Maybe a
fromTime NoTime = Nothing
fromTime (Time x) = Just x
```

Comment: I didnot know about the importance of the terms order, very good point!